# BigQuery - No mathcing signature for operator CASE in conjunction with CAST to INT64

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT 
    T.myString, #A string that contains a number
    CASE CAST(T.myString as INT64)
    WHEN CAST(T.myString as INT64) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END AS test

FROM 
    `main.tables.test` T
```

This shows the error:

```
" No mathcing signature for operator CASE for argument types INT64, BOOL ... "
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is the "fix"

```
SELECT 
    T.myString, #A string that contains a number
    CASE 
    WHEN CAST(T.myString as INT64) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END AS test

FROM 
    `main.tables.test` T
```

or

```
SELECT 
    T.myString, #A string that contains a number
    CASE CAST(T.myString as INT64) > 0
    WHEN true THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END AS test

FROM 
    `main.tables.test` T
```

Answer (score 1):

Try bare [CASE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case):

```
SELECT 
  T.myString, #A string that contains a number
  CASE
    WHEN CAST(T.myString as INT64) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS test
FROM 
  `main.tables.test` T
```